# create mysql stored procedure to generate db

Tags: mysql, procedure

I´m working in a multy-database system and I would like your opinion about create a database from stored procedures in mysql. It´s work fine, but I would like if anybody use this technique before, and if it could be a problem in the future.

This is an example of pseudo code of the workflow of my procedure:

mainProcedure :
-Create DB and Users
Flush priveleges;

Call procedureToPopulateNewDatabase(nameOfNewDataBase)

END of procedures.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Creating database isn't an operation performed repeatedly.
Maybe it would be useful to use scripts to automate operations with tables.
For example: Suppose you've created table1. After that you've created table2 which contains column(s) that references table1.column1
It is interesting to have a script capable of dropping your tables relashionship. In the example, your script are going to drop table2 first, then table1.
If we try to drop table1 first it would throw an error due to referencial integrity.

Comment: Thanks for your response Junior. I´m going to continue with this solution and i´ll come back to tell about the results. Your solution it´s ok, but it´s harder to write, and the result is similar. My procedures only are executed when the other is finished...